# MS ReportViewer is not applying custom paper size

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, rdlc, custom-pages

I have developed my application on C# winform. I designed my report on rdlc report in Visual studio 2013. I am using report viewer to generate preview of the report and print the report.

The report paper size is a custom paper. That is width: 19cm x Height: 20cm. But when I see my report in report viewer, it shows the report in A4 page.

I set the page size in report properties in design mode. But that is not taking effect.

I tried to set the page size at run time. But it is also not taking effect.

I tried this code.

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings PS = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
                PS.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", (int)((19 * 0.393701) * 100), (int)((20 * 0.393701) * 100));
                PS.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                PS.Landscape = false;


                RepViewer.SetPageSettings(PS);
```

Is there any way to use custom paper size with RDLC report and MS Report Viewer.

IF No, then please suggest any alternate solution for it that should be free.

Comment: Check `GetDefaultPageSettings()` value in your `LocalReport`.

Comment: Also check the `deviceinfo` value passing to `report.Render` method

Comment: Getting this error while calling GetDefaultPageSettings() method.
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.MissingReportSourceException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll

Additional information: The source of the report definition has not been specified

Answer (score 0):

I think you just add this code end code of you, it will save code your did custom above:

```
[YourNameReportViewer].RefreshReport();
```